# Add Breakline to jQuery each result

Tags: php, mysql, json, jquery

I have a problem, I have been trying to solve this for a while, I have a search box, that fires a GET method using php+mysql+jquery+json, upon returning the json result I then display it on the DOM, now here's my issue, i use the following code to display the result;

```
success:function(data){         
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {

            for( var item in data ) {
            //alert(data[key].category);
            }

            //cleanup();
                $("<a />", {
                    href: data[index].userid,
                    text: data[index].category
                })
                .appendTo("#divResultPlaceHolder")
                .css({
                    color: "red",
                    size: "35px",
                    display:"block"
                });

                //$("<br/>").appendTo("a");   <<<<<<<============does work but does not meet requirements
                $(":input[type='checkbox']").insertBefore("a");
            });
```

then the resulting DOM display would be something like this;

```
SecretaryC# ProgrammerAccountantSr. AccountantVP for FinanceAccounting Manager
```

In these manner, I want it to break a line for each returned result; however, adding the `<br/>` doesn't help at all as it appears to add a breakline (x) the no. of elements per execution of each,

I wish to have the display like this;

```
Secretary
C# Programmer
Accountant
Sr. Accountant
VP for Finance
so on so forth....
```

I know I just missed something somewhere, but maybe my eyes have grown tired to stared back at a wide white screen for several hours.

P

Comment: use \ instead of `<br/>`

Comment: Your display:"block" on `.css()` should be taking care of that. What what is "size"? Do you mean `width`?

Comment: @bfavaretto, I see, could have been a work of some witchcraft on me, anyway, yes, the display:block should be enough.... hmmm I wonder the page didn't reflect the changes immediately, could have accidentally missed the refresh button. anyway, that did it. thanks. cheers!

Comment: Could you wrap each result in a `<p>` element?

Comment: how can you add points, accept an answer that is just a comment?

Answer (score -1):

Normally if you want to break line with dynamically generated html or normal string, just use \n instead of 
 or any thing else.

else

```
Secretary\n
C# Programmer\n
Accountant\n
Sr. Accountant\n
VP for Finance\n
etc
```